# In-App Purchase is not working in iOS7

Tags: in-app-purchase, ios7

I have a working code for In-App purchase , its working fine in iOS6 but when I run in iOS7 I got "Failed to load list of products" in debug area and when I tap on restore button to get the already purchased product it says "Cannot connect to iTunes Store". 
I searched a lot but did not found any solution for this.
Please suggest

Comment: I think, you have tested this on simulator... Please try it on device...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is also happening for past few days on all iOS-es. Most of the time it gives same message on device as well. Though I have I know the code I have does not any issue and when I submitted to app and it is approved, it works perfectly. It looks like some issue with sandbox env.

Answer (score 0):

DId you test it on simulator?

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW241

StoreKit (In-App purchases) will not work in the Simulator. 13962338